# Why I don't have motion blur in hair? (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, particles

I have no motion blur in a character's hair, but I have it in the base mesh. As you can see in the image below, the base mesh is blurred but the hair of the character is not blurred at all. It looks static.

[image]

I know there's a render time limitation for this, but in this case there's no motion blur at all. Is deactivated or something?

I'm using Blender 2.76 and nothing special with the hair, in this case is not even combed. The blurring method is Deformation motion blur.

Comment: try adding some more detail about the hair setup, and the blurring method and settings used... blender version...

Comment: You're totally right. I've edited but there's nothing important to add besides Blender's version.

Comment: I mean: I tried this simple test (and it seems to work here, 2.76): default cube, added particle system with type: "hair" (anything else default), enabled "motion blur", (default shutter, 0.5)... or can you share a file (see blend-exchange: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: it should be possible since 2.71, afaik 
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.71/Cycles

Comment: Yeah, I did that test too. But you need to add an armature 'cos this problem appears with deformation motion Blur. I did a new hair system for this character and everything works fine but, somehow, it brokes at some point. I need to test a little bit more to find out where the problem is.